# Getting common fields of two tables in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose  `Table A`  and  `Table B`  have various fields. What is an easy way to get the common fields among  `Table A`  and  `Table B` ? I want to do an inner join on these tables but I don't know what the common fields are.

Note that this is in PL/SQL. When I table  `A.`  or  `B.`  I get the list of fields names of each table in a drop down menu. But I would like to get the common fields.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Does this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9931b/1) possibly help you to re-phrase your question?

Comment: [tag:plsql] doesn't have drop down menus. The question can be answered with plain [tag:oracle][tag:sql].

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean by "common fields".

If you want to get all colums which names are the same in both tables, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT t1.column_name
FROM user_tab_columns t1
JOIN user_tab_columns t2
ON t1.COLUMN_NAME = t2.COLUMN_NAME
/* 
   AND t1.DATA_TYPE = t2.DATA_TYPE
   AND t1.DATA_LENGTH = t2.DATA_LENGTH
*/
WHERE t1.table_name = 'A'
  AND t2.table_name = 'B'
  ;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b662/1

But if you look at tables in the above demo, you will see that table `A` has a column named `X` with datatype `VARCHAR2`, and table `B` has also a column named `X` but of different type `INT`.

If you want to get all columns that have **the same names, the same datatypes and the same length**, then uncomment respective conditions in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Do mean something like this:

```
TableA has 2 columns: Id and Name. 
TableB has 2 columns: Name and PhoneNumber
```

Query:

```
SELECT  A.Id, A.Name, B.PhoneNumber 
FROM    TableA A, TableB B 
WHERE   A.Name = B.Name;
```

Edit:

If you want know what Columns names there a re from your table I believe you can use `DESC TableA`. Then you get a list a column names. You can use those to compaire against another list, for example from TableB.